# Spring Security login page with Angular not working

Tags: angular, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I'm trying to do Spring + Angular app with login page using Spring Security.

I'm having problems with sending request to spring from angular (also logging page). I'm quite new in both technologies and don't have a clue what I do wrong.

Logging in works with postman (post request "localhost:8080/auth" with form-data {username, password}).
I did custom login page with angular and tried to send post and get requests (with the same username/pasword):

```
loginUser(username: string | undefined, password: string | undefined) {
    const headers = new HttpHeaders(username ? {
      authorization : 'Basic ' + btoa(username + ':' + password)
    } : {});
    console.log(username)
    console.log(password)
    this.http.post(this.uri + "/auth", {headers}).subscribe(response => {
        console.log(response);
    });
```

Username and password returned by console.log are ok.
Request returns code 302 and spring sends **login?error** page with "Invalid credentials" spring security page.
If i change post to get, request returns 404 (and does not return login error), which postman returns also  - but in postman authorization works and later I can send other requests - In angular I can't - other request returns 302 and spring security login page.

My spring WebSecurityConfig:

```
@Configuration
@AllArgsConstructor
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    private final AppUserService userService;
    private final BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors().configurationSource(request -> new CorsConfiguration().applyPermitDefaultValues())
                .and()
                .csrf().disable() //to delete
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/v*/registration/**", "/login", "/auth")
                .permitAll()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginProcessingUrl("/auth")
                .usernameParameter("username")
                .passwordParameter("password")
                .permitAll()
                .and().logout().permitAll().and()
                .httpBasic()
        ;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(daoAuthenticationProvider());
    }

    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider daoAuthenticationProvider(){
        DaoAuthenticationProvider provider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        provider.setPasswordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder);
        provider.setUserDetailsService(userService);
        return provider;

    }
```

Comment: first of all you can remove the `configure`function and the creation of `DaoAuthenticationProvider` as spring security will create all of this for you automatically as long as you provide the encoder and userservice as beans. Second of all you are saying that in postman `FormLogin` works, but then in your Angular app you are doing `Basic` login. You are aware that basic and form login are two different things? so how are you gonna have it, are you doing FormLogin? or doing Basic login?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was on your Angular function `loginUser`.

The first authentication you must sent the parameters on the body request not on the header request.
Please remove the below headers.

```
 const headers = new HttpHeaders(username ? {
           authorization : 'Basic ' + btoa(username + ':' + password)
         } : {});
```

You must sent token on the authorization headres for the other authenticated requests

At loginUser you can just sent like below

```
this.http.post(this.uri + "/auth", { username, password }).subscribe(response => {
        console.log(response);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

there might be issue with angular, please check the code below

please checkout the code below & ( body of the request )

```
this.http.post(this.uri + "/auth", 
               { username, password} )
               .subscribe(response => {
        console.log(response);
    });
```